# Ant table custom filter checkbox without dropdown

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, filter, antd, tablefilter

I am using ant table for my project where I want to filter records on click of checkbox inside my header row, when I click on check box all zero valued rows should be filtered and others should stay, is there any way I can do this?
[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-and-sorter-antd4168-forked-od1hx?file=/index.js)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired feature by defining a custom `columns` `title` prop that renders a controlled `Checkbox` component in addition to the column's title string. When the `Checkbox` is true, you then filter out the table `data` based on your desired filter condition.

(As an aside, I did initially try to get the same functionality to work via the `onFilter` and `filterIcon` approach, but that approach proved unsuccessful.)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Table, Checkbox } from "antd";
import "./index.scss";

const DifferenceTable = (props) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const data = [
    {
      date: "2020-06-17",
      units: 2353.0,
      amount: 8891206.27,
      date: 2323,
      units: 243234,
      amount: 234234,
      units_diff: 0,
      amount_diff: 0
    },
    {
      date: "2020-06-17",
      units: 2353.0,
      amount: 8891206.27,
      date: 2323,
      units: 243234,
      amount: 234234,
      units_diff: 1,
      amount_diff: 1
    }
  ];

  const processedData = isChecked
    ? data.filter((datum) => datum.units_diff || datum.amount_diff)
    : data;
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Bank",
      children: [
        {
          title: "Trxn Date",
          dataIndex: "date",
          key: "date",
          width: 100
        },
        {
          title: "Sum Units",
          dataIndex: "units",
          key: "units",
          width: 100
        },
        {
          title: "Sum Amounts",
          dataIndex: "amount",
          key: "units",
          width: 100
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "CUSTOMER",
      children: [
        {
          title: "Trxn Date",
          dataIndex: "date",
          key: "date",
          width: 100
        },
        {
          title: "Sum Units",
          dataIndex: "units",
          key: "units",
          width: 100
        },
        {
          title: "Sum Amounts",
          dataIndex: "amount",
          key: "amount",
          width: 100
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: () => (
        <div>
          <span>Difference&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
          <Checkbox
            checked={isChecked}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setIsChecked(e.target.checked);
            }}
          />
        </div>
      ),
      dataIndex: "units_diff",
      key: "units_diff",
      children: [
        {
          title: "Units",
          dataIndex: "units_diff",
          key: "units_diff",
          width: 100
        },
        {
          title: "Amounts",
          dataIndex: "amount_diff",
          key: "amount_diff",
          width: 100
        }
      ],
      align: "center"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Table
      // rowKey="uid"
      className="table diff_table"
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={processedData}
      pagination={false}
      scroll={{ y: 400, x: 0 }}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<DifferenceTable />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

A functional demo is available at the following [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-custom-header-filter-checkbox-v9yhm?file=/index.js:0-2582)

Comment: Thank you for your help it is very useful!!

Comment: a simple and working solution, nice